# How to use EUInformation on a OPC-UA server (C#)?

Tags: c#, xml, opc-ua

I'm new in OPC-UA. I looked into the reference SDK and some online tutorial.
I'm creating a OPC-UA server for a simulation of an industrial machine.

I created my xml model with some motors and sensors. They both have an AnalogItemType variable.
I'm taking the motor in example:

```
<opc:ObjectType SymbolicName="Motor" BaseType="ua:BaseObjectType">
        <opc:Description>A motor.</opc:Description>
        <opc:Children>
            <opc:Variable SymbolicName="Speed" DataType="ua:Double" ValueRank="Scalar" TypeDefinition="ua:AnalogItemType" AccessLevel="ReadWrite" />
            <opc:Method SymbolicName="Start" ModellingRule="Mandatory"></opc:Method>
            <opc:Method SymbolicName="Stop" ModellingRule="Mandatory"></opc:Method>
        </opc:Children>
    </opc:ObjectType>
```

I use the UA.ModelCompiler (from OPC-UA Foundation) to compile the xml and generate the code for the server.
I use the Reference client in the Reference SDK.

When I run my server, I can see only the EURange property of the AnalogItem and not the EngineeringUnits (both should be optional and not mandatory).

I tried to set both in my NodeManager.cs :

```
Server.Motor.Speed.EURange.Value = new Opc.Ua.Range() {Hingh = 900, Low = 100};
Server.Motor.Speed.EngineeringUnits.Value = new EUInformation("rad", "radiants", "http://www.opcfoundation.org/UA/units/un/cefact");
```

The first instruction is ok but the second throws an exception because, it says, the EngineeringUnits is null (while the EURange is of type [Variable]EURange).

How can I set the EngineeringUnits (and maybe diable EURange) in my C# code?

How can I enable the EngineeringUnits (and maybe diable EURange) in the MyModelDesign.xml?